# Internet Explorer and proxy PAC file problem

Tags: webdriver

I'm having trouble with making IE use proxy pac file. But it works ok with Firefox and Chrome.

What I do:

1) Prepare proxy config

```
proxyPacFile = "file:///" + proxyPacFile;

Proxy proxyPAC = new Proxy();
proxyPAC.setProxyAutoconfigUrl(proxyPacFile);
proxyPAC.setProxyType(ProxyType.PAC);
```

2) Set proxy config to capabilities:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_USE_PRE_PROCESS_PROXY, true);              
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxyPAC);
```

3) Then start RemoteWebDriver with that capabilities

And it doesn't work for IE. In connection settings I can see that address to file is correct, but IE doesn't open any page. Meanwhile in Firefox and Chrome everything works ok. Here's how I set capabilities for them:

```
    case CHROME:                
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();                
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxyPAC);             
        break;

    case FIREFOX:
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();              
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2); 
        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxyPAC);             
        break;
```

Do I need some extra capability for IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, Internet Explorer 11 disable to read pac file pointing to them as a file:///. The problem solved by transferring the file to an internal Web server and pointing to it as http link